# Pyserial bluetooth working only at 9600 baud rate

Tags: python, bluetooth, arduino, pyserial

I'm working on an arduino sending a sensor value on Serial.

Everything works great by USB.

But when we use the bluetooth module we can't go any further than 9600 baudrate.
At more than 9600 baudrate serial.readline() just never return, even with a short timeout.

We use an arduino Uno with a bluetooth dongle BTH-07 from elecfreaks, and pyserial on python 3.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reading the [documentation](http://www.elecfreaks.com/store/download/datasheet/Bluetooth/Bluetooth%20HC-06.pdf), did you try to send the baudrate change AT command before changing the connection baudrate?

```
>>> AT+BAUD8
<<< OK115200
```

then, afaict, you'd have to power cycle the dongle, and reconnect at 115200 bps.